# Is it safe to delete `/usr/local/bin`?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I previously used Node installed from the website, and I've recently started using `nvm`. I deleted `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, and was about the delete `/usr/local/bin` as well, but noticed there were a bunch of modules in it that I didn't recognize.

**What I Want To Know:** Does `/usr/loca/bin` contain anything other than modules installed via `npm i -g`? In other words, if I delete `/usr/local/bin` and just start re-installing all the global modules that I need via `npm i -g`, are there any risks to that? When I install global modules now, they get saved in `~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/lib`.

Comment: No don’t delete it lmao. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/what-is-usr-local-bin

Comment: I concur with previous comment :D

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to delete `/usr/local/bin`?

Absolutely not. It will destroy other applications you installed on your machine as well. It's the install path for all binaries that should survive operating system changes/upgrades. (It's a bit like asking "Is it safe to delete `C:\Program Files`?" in Windows.)

You should delete only `/usr/local/bin/node` and all of the now-broken symlinks into `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` (since you deleted the folder - symlinks such as `npm` but possibly others as well if you globally installed any packages that provide CLIs). I'm assuming you have GNU `find`, then you can use the `-xtype l` option to find broken links:

```sh
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node
sudo find /usr/local/bin -xtype l -delete
```

Comment: 1) What's an example of a binary in this path that I wouldn't be able to just re-install with `npm i -g <package>`? 2) I looked up the xtype option but am confused; does the command you listed find all symlinks that are stored in /usr/local/bin and point to modules in /usr/local/lib/node_modules, or specifically the ones that are broken? I'm assuming it just finds the symlinks, but since I deleted /usr/local/lib/node_modules, we assume all those symlinks are broken.

Comment: 1) Depends on what else you have installed on your system, I have there for example `apktool`, `aws`, `bundler`, `caddy`, `easy_install`, `electrum`, `elm`, `jekyll`, `markdown2`, `meteor`, `pip`, `pip3`, `powerline`, `update_rubygems`, among other things. You get the idea. 2) `-xtype l` finds all broken links. Since you deleted `lib/node_modules`, all the links pointing there will now be broken. It works because the `xtype` would return the type of the _target_ of the link, but if the target can't be found, it returns `l`.